# Index mathematical symbols

Tags: math-mode, indexing, makeindex, makeidx

I want to put mathematical symbols in my index. For example, `\vec` and `@`. To this end I wrote a command that sorts mathematical index entries to the beginning of the index. Sometimes the command works and another time it prints garbled index entries or even raises compile errors.

From the minimal working example …

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\newcommand\mindex[1]{\index{ @#1}}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

% works as expected
$A\cup B$ is the union.
\mindex{$\cdot\cup \cdot$}

% works, but prints garbled text in the index
$\vec{v}$ is a vector.
\mindex{$\vec{\cdot}$}

% commented line doesn't compile. Error "Missing $ inserted"
$\langle \phi|$ is a bra-ket.
%\mindex{$\langle \cdot|$}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

I use `latexmk -pdf` to compile the document and get

[image: document]

[image: index]

The generated `.idx` file is

```
\indexentry{ @$\cdot \cup \cdot $}{1}
\indexentry{ @$\mathaccent "017E\relax {\cdot }$}{1}
```

#### How can I put arbitrary math expressions into the index?

I already played around with `\protect` and `\DeclareRobustCommand` but had no luck. The [documentation of `makeindex`](http://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/indexing/makeindex/doc/makeindex.pdf) states

> To put a `!`, `@`, or `|` character in an index entry, quote it by preceding the character with a `"`.

so I replaced `\mindex{$\vec{\cdot}$}` with `\mindex{$\mathaccent ""017E\relax {\cdot}$}` and it worked. I also can compile `\mindex{$\langle \cdot"|$}` but have no idea on how to get the `\lange` right. And even if I did, I would prefer to write `\langle` instead of some obscure sequence of core commands.

Comment: There are several things at play here. First `{  @...}` is plain wrong, an entry like `\index{  @B}` is sorted as the empty string which gives a strange order. Next remember that `|` has a special meaning in indexes indicating sub entries, so `\mindex{$\langle \cdot|$}` is basically the same as `\indexentry $langle cdot \indexsubentry $` which of course is wrong. There are no real shortcuts here.

Comment: Note that everything works if you do not use `\mindex`, and `\detokenize{...}` in `#1` in the definition of `\mindex` seems to work. But as mentioned abobe the sorting is probably all over the place (but that might be intentionally)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wouldn't say that `{ @...}` is »*plain wrong*«. It's strange but exactly what I want. I could also write `{AAAAA@...}` but think that the first version is clearer. Anyways, I'd like to use a wrapper around `\index`  to hide that strange `{ @...}`. If `\index` works then there has to be a way to make `\mindex` work.

Comment: It is all about expansion, index handles its contents specially so care is needed to make sure we do not get premature expansion. If this is for example for a book, I'd probably use something like `\index{union@$\cdot \cup \cdot $ (union)}` to have it sorted in a way the user expect.

Comment: Tried your suggestion to use `\dektonize` -- worked like a charm. If you write an answer I'll gladly accept it. ¶ Your suggestion `\index{union@$\cup$}` is not what. `\mindex` is for strange symbols where the reader might not know the name of the symbol. These (few) symbols should be sorted to the beginning of the index to save the reader from having to skim the whole index for that symbol.

Comment: Try using \MakeRobustCommand{\vec} so that the \vec could not expand in the output. documentation available in the below link: https://ctan.org/pkg/makerobust?lang=en